# Can K8S pods marked as "Not ready" still receive direct requests?

Tags: kubernetes, readinessprobe

Say you have a K8S pod that has a readiness probe set up, and at some point that probe fails. The [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes) say that the pod remains alive but is marked as "Not ready" and "does not receive traffic through Kubernetes Services". When that happens, do requests made **directly to the pod's IP address** still succeed? What about existing websocket connections to that pod - do they remain connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests should still succeed if you use pod's IP address.

[Readiness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes) are used to determine if a pod is ready to receive traffic from kubernetes services, which if it's in "Not Ready" state, the pod shall not be included as endpoint or backend services.

Websocket is a communication protocol used in client-server communication like HTTP requests. [HTTP probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#http-probes) are part of liveness and startup probes, wherein the kubelet will send a HTTP request in the specified path and port number to the pod's IP to perform a check.

Since it can be part of the liveness probe, it should not affect the readiness probe because it doesn't wait for it to succeed as stated from the [official docs.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes)